# Spring Authentication Look in other Sessions

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I know that I can getAllSessions for user with current active session, and I know I can getAllPrincipals that will show all users with active sessions. But I want to know if it is possible to getAllSessions for a specific user. So say I am userA with current active session and I want to getAllPrincipals and then choose one of the principals and then getAllSessions for that specific principal. Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about [`SessionRegistry`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html) and in the API there is [`getAllSessions(Object principal, boolean includeExpiredSessions)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html#getAllSessions%28java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) method you can use. For example:

```
List<Object> allPrincipals = getAllPrincipals();
Object principal = allPrincipals.get(0); // change this to way you want
List<SessionInformation> principalSessions = getAllSessions(principal, false);
```

Just remember that principal object can be anything, like [`User`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) or your own implementation, but **it has to define `equals()` and `hashCode`** properly.